# I can't see the view twig into my module

Tags: theming, 8

I have test already to an over module for seeing the view but it doesnt work.

I have used the Drupal Console project (i can't tag it :/ ). I dont understant why i can see the view Twig. When you can see with the link to the github project, i have create into the module hello_world the repertory "templates" who they have into the "world.html.twig"

My HelloController has located into src/Controller/HelloController.php

```
/**
 * @file
 * Contains \Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloController.
 */

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Class HelloController.
 *
 * @package Drupal\hello_world\Controller
 */
class HelloController extends ControllerBase {
  /**
   * World.
   *
   * @return string
   *   Return Hello string.
   */
  public function world() {
    return [
        '#theme' => 'world',
        '#texte' => $this->t('Hello world ! ')
    ];
  }
```

}

Where comming my error? From the Controller, fromm the hook?

```
/*hello_world.module*/
function hello_world_theme() {

    return array(
        'world' => array(
            'template' => 'world',
            'variables' => array('texte' => NULL)
        ),
    );

}
```

I'm bloking on this since 2 day.

Github project : 
https://github.com/emilienGallet/DrupalUnicef/commit/2d46cee1a5b12f9ab8ef59d16a39ccfd7ce0769a

Command of Drupal console executed before :

1. drupal generate:module
2. drupal generate:controller
3. drupal cache:rebuild

Thanks for the Future Helping :)

Comment: Probleme resolve. It's due to a braces onto hello_world.module (i havent modified but it's due to that into my git depot.)